# Why is the Bid & Ask not filled in this example [Level 2 Picture]

Tags: stocks

[image]

Can someone explain why the orders are not getting filled?

Comment: Is there a link to this chart

Comment: What software is this?

Answer (score 3):

Because the last trade H10.35 means Trade Halt. During such halt, new orders can be entered but not executed until the halt is lifted.

After the halt, there will be auctioning process to determine the "cross", similar to market opening auction.

The "cross" price would result in greatest volume transacted the moment the halt is lifted.

https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/ProductsServices/Trading/IPOHalt/haltcross_fs.pdf

Comment: Good catch (the halt).